# Angular: $q.all not working on a map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I need to execute something only after a multiple of AJAX calls got their response so I'm using $q.all to wait until all promises were

```
var promises = myServices.map(function (service) {  
        return $http.get(service.url);

    });

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(data) {
       doAll();
});
```

For some reason, `doAll` is never called. However, if I do the following it works fine:

```
$q.all([$http.get(serviceA.url), $http.get(serviceB.url)])
    .then(function(data) {
       doAll();
});
```

Comment: do you check console.log for errors? Where is your closing ']' in $q.all?

Comment: is the console something telling you? my suggestion is that some of your promice do not resolves. Try to put console log in each service and see if all of them do the job. If myServices contain serviceA, serviceB and some other services it is possible that serviceA and serviceB works fine but serviceC is fails

Comment: looking for the syntax - everything fine

Comment: Tried to reproduce. [Map is working fine.](https://plnkr.co/edit/aqhFPQ?p=preview)

Comment: Can you confirm that `myServices` is exactly `[serviceA, serviceB]`?